# Cannot Resolve class TextView in xml file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I just changed my Laptop, downloaded Android Studio Arctic Fox and cloned the project on which I was already working on in my previous machine. I see that few of the tags are not imported and are in red in the xml layout. When I hover over it, it says "Cannot resolve class TextView". Similar issue with ImageView. What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: This might be gradle issue. Just try to invalidate cache and restart studio. Or try to syc gradle (while requesting gradle sync make sure you are not in offline mode).

Comment: @ChhatrasalSinghBundela tried, didn't work.

Comment: Delete .idea file and .gradle files(folders)  and try to sync the gradle again

Answer (score 4):

I also facing the same problem for 2 days, try lots of the way but didn't work. But a few minutes ago I **just update my Glradle**  to the

**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'**

and boom it's solved my problem. You can try this :)

Comment: it's work with  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2' for me so you have to change classpath to latest version

Comment: Yeah just change the classpath to the latest version hope it will be work

Comment: To make Android Studio to do this, goto Tools->AGP Upgrade Assistant and Run Upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

***after clean the project sync the build gradle or cut and paste a one dependency  and sync the gradle***

Answer (score 0):

This error but made a struggle 3 days; I solved it by upgrading gradle to the latest version on this day gradle: 7.0.3 at the classpath level (build.gradle (project))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30257962)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by set Gradle user home ：
1.File -〉Project Structure -〉SDK Location -〉Gradle Setting -〉Gradle user home （select your local）

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and i after consideration there can be

1)problem in your gradle version(which is not in my case)

2)I am writing code below this line

```
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

write all your code above this.

which caused trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably, you might have been using androidx libraries.
Try   `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView`

instead of
`<TextView`

Comment: AndroidX automatically translates TextView to AppCompatTextView, so explicitly using the longer version in layout files causes more visual mess.